# how to import 3 xml selectors in one drupal field using the migrate plus module?

Tags: migrations, importing-exporting

the migrate_plus migration conf i had so far was

```
process:     
  title: title
  body: job_description
  field_job_diffusion: offer_type
  field_job_statut: statut
  field_job_domaine: domaine
  field_job_campus: campus
  field_job_niveau_etudes: study_level
  field_job_emailapi: application_email
```

It works for single XML selector to single field mapping and migration.
I need now to get the value from 3 xml selectors and put them in one multivalued field.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: i feel sorry it is down-voted as it is less than obvious to find the doc on how to use these migration yml files and now thanks to @Joseph it cleared up my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs has a list of process plugins from [core](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-core-migrate-process-plugins) and [migrate plus](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-process-plugins-provided-by-migrate-plus) you can use to manipulate the data before they get set on the field.

[`get`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21Get.php/class/Get) is the plugin used by Drupal when you use the shorthand mapping syntax (i.e. how you're doing it right now). However, you can write the longhand version, *it also accepts an array* as source, which it will then treat as a multi-value source. Simply pop an array of the source field names into an array as the `source`:

```
process:
  field_phone_numbers:
    -
      plugin: get
      source:
        - main_number
        - mobile_number
        - office_number
```